# My google map android app keeps crashing

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps-api-2

I have followed about two tutorials from vogella and some other tutorial that looked similar...very similar but to no avail. I load the app on my nexus 7 and it just crashes "Unfortunately MyMapView has stopped working" on launch.This is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.macmozart.mymapview"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>    
<permission
    android:name="com.macmozart.mymapview.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission
 android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.macmozart.mymapview.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBZ1Bt7rjB863Jy-B05zls6k8XZsBGQ6-4" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

Followed by my main layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and finally my java class:

```
package com.macmozart.mymapview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.maps.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
    static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();

        if (map != null) {
            Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(HAMBURG).title("Hamburg"));
            Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(KIEL)
                    .title("Kiel")
                    .snippet("Kiel is cool")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));
            // Zoom in, animating the camera.
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);

        }

    }
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong I really need this to work

**EDIT** :After exporting logcat log to txt file I just copied:

```
10-19 11:45:08.565: W/dalvikvm(638): Class resolved by unexpected DEX: Lcom/macmozart/mymapview/MainActivity;(0x4231c508):0x418ce000 ref [Lcom/google/android/maps/MapActivity;] Lcom/google/android/maps/MapActivity;(0x4231c508):0x40064000
10-19 11:45:08.565: W/dalvikvm(638): (Lcom/macmozart/mymapview/MainActivity; had used a different Lcom/google/android/maps/MapActivity; during pre-verification)
10-19 11:45:08.565: W/dalvikvm(638): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/macmozart/mymapview/MainActivity; (1310)
10-19 11:45:08.565: W/dalvikvm(638): Link of class 'Lcom/macmozart/mymapview/MainActivity;' failed
10-19 11:45:08.575: D/AndroidRuntime(638): Shutting down VM
10-19 11:45:08.575: W/dalvikvm(638): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41bbc700)
10-19 11:45:08.575: E/AndroidRuntime(638): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-19 11:45:08.575: E/AndroidRuntime(638): java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
10-19 11:45:08.575: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(Native Method)
10-19 11:45:08.575: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:211)
10-19 11:45:08.575: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:313)
10-19 11:45:08.575: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:51)
10-19 11:45:08.575: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
10-19 11:45:08.575: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
10-19 11:45:08.575: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
10-19 11:45:08.575: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
10-19 11:45:08.575: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-19 11:45:08.575: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-19 11:45:08.575: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-19 11:45:08.575: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-19 11:45:08.575: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-19 11:45:08.575: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-19 11:45:08.575: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-19 11:45:08.575: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-19 11:45:08.575: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-19 11:45:08.575: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-19 11:45:08.575: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-19 11:45:10.905: I/Process(638): Sending signal. PID: 638 SIG: 9
```

Comment: can u post logcat plz ?

Comment: i just exported it to a txt file,check my edit

Comment: Post details on your `Project > Properties > Android` and `Project > Properties > Java Build Path`

Comment: Under android the only thing ticked is Android 4.3 .<br> and under Java there is android-support-v4.jar,google-play-services.jar,maps.jar,android 4.3,android dependencies and android private libraries

Comment: try to put this in your manifest uses sdk <uses-permission android:name="com.macmozart.mymapview.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanx for all the help I realised I hadnt selected the Google APIs as @Kalpesh Lakhani pointed out so decided to start from scratch only that this time imported the lib project from google play services in extras, then under Project > Properties > Android > IsLibrary I referenced the libproject. Got a new key from Google API console,added all the permissions needed and under my main xml defined a new fragments as
 
    `<fragment 
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />`
,Ran the program and just the map is showing hopefully as I read on to tagging locations I wont have any errors, thank u guys though. P.S. I didnt need to add the external JAR files hopefully when i'm exporting there is a detailed explanation since google-lib project is showing as a project as well.
[Reference video for this code,helps ALOT!!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awX5T-EwLPc)

Comment: only in 2 days it says

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your MainActivity class is likely extending com.google.android.maps.MapActivity. For the system to be able to find this class you need to do two things:

First make sure your project is including the Android maps.jar in your build path. From Eclipse find

```
Project > Properties > Android
```

Then select one of the "Google APIs" as appropriate for you app. You can confirm that maps.jar is on your build path by checking:

```
Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Expand "Google Apis"
```

Second browse to your manifest file and make sure you have the uses-library snippet nested within the  tags as follows:

```
<manifest>
...
   <application ...>
      <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
      ...
   </application>
</manifest>
```

May the force be with you!

Comment: and then in my main xml how exactly do i define it?

Comment: @Manny264 do you mean how do you actually see the map?

Comment: check my answer below i used an imported project from google play services and referenced it in my own project

Answer (score 1):

Check that maps.jar is not included twice in your build path. You should only include it in the `libs/` folder in your project - then it will turn up in "Android private libraries" in the Java Build Path > Libraries - delete it in the build path from all other places (including android dependencies if there)

Clean and rebuild

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is correct.

I would remove maps.jar of the library tab of your project build path and then you have to choose Google Apis in your Android project properties .